# print doesn't work in __getattr__

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this class:

```
class Meta:
    def __getattr__(self, atr):
        print('get', atr)
    def __setattr__(self, atr, atr_value):
        print('{0} with value {1} added'.format(atr, atr_value))
        self.__dict__[atr] = atr_value
```

and when I set an attribute - `print` works:

```
>>> x.a = 1
a with value 1 added
```

but when I call it:

```
>>> x.a
1
```

Value is returned without the `print` output.

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__getattr__` is called only when the attribute does not exist. You want to override `__gettattribute__`.

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    print("get", name)
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Answer (score 2):

In new-style classes [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)(true for old style classes as well) is called only if the attribute cannot be found on the instance or its class(well this includes the base classes as well).

In new-style classes you can achieve this by overriding [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__).

Answer (score 2):

If the attribute is in the class or the instance dictionary, `__getattr__` won't be called. This is an intentional asymmetry from `__setattr__`.

Implement `__getattribute__` if you want full control.